# Local Binary features with unit16 images vs unit8 images

Tags: matlab, feature-extraction, lbph-algorithm

I have unit16 image dataset, and I want to extract LBP features from them using  Matlab function `extractLBPFeatures`, which uses uniform LBP (59 features). 
so when I apply it on unit 16 image  it gives the below:

[image]

but with unit8 images it gives

[image]

what could be the reason? Is it because that the LBP uses histogram that can be seen as a 256-dimensional (0 - 255), if so, how to deal with unit16 images

here is the code

```
im16 = imread('I_rec_no_color.tif');
im8 = imread('I_rec_no_color_8.tif');
LBP16 = extractLBPFeatures(im16);
LBP8= extractLBPFeatures(im8 );
```

Comment: Please show your code. See [mcve]. `extractLBPFeatures` is supposed to support uint16 images, so if it doesn't work, submit a bug report to the MathWorks. Also, the histogram has nothing to do with the number of different grey levels in the image.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand that this function gives LBP in the range 0 to 255, and because the the image "im16"  (uint16) intesities are in the range of [525 633], so i beleive when extractin the LBP, all the values will be in one bin? not sure though

Comment: No, LBP only compares the values of a pixel and its neighbors, returning a series of 0s and 1s (for smaller and larger). When looking at 8 neighbors, 8 bits are obtained, which can be seen as a value in the range 0-255. This 255 is unrelated to the bit depth of the image, it is related to the number of neighbors. I recommend that you read up on the method before trying to use it.

Comment: yes, you're correct, so that means the reason why 58 uniform patterns give more results for uint8 images than uint16 is not related to the bit of depth of the images. So, in this case, extracting the whole 256 feature might give better results